# How to use components inside behavioral vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have created a divided with core generator. It creates a component like the following:

```
component divider_core
port (
clk: IN std_logic;
rfd: OUT std_logic;
dividend: IN std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
divisor: IN std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
quotient: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
fractional: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0));
end component;
```

I wonder how I could use this divider component by some behavioral vhdl code, inside a process. Is that possible?

Comment: I have experience with VHDL since 2009. Why do you say that?

Comment: Because you can't instantiate a component inside a process.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have created your module you need to declare the component in the architecture section and map the ports of the component before the process.

You can see how it applies to your code below

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity declaration 

architecture Behavioral of <your_entity> is

component divider_core
port (
 clk: IN std_logic;
 rfd: OUT std_logic;
 dividend: IN std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
 divisor: IN std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
 quotient: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
 fractional: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0));
end component;

begin

c1: divider_core Port Map (
 clk => clk,
 rfd => rfd,
 dividend => dividend,
 divisor => divisor,
 quotient => quotient,
 fractional => fractional
);

process

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thanks for that!!! Really interesting! However, my process needs multiple dividers. If I have only one divider "port mapped" how can I use multiple dividers inside my process?

Comment: if you need multiple dividers simply map more, for instance:
c2: divider_core Port Map ()
c3: divider_core Port Map ()
Hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `numeric_std` package ([link](http://www.eda.org/rassp/vhdl/models/standards/numeric_std.vhd)) and use the division (`/`) operator.

Comment: I mean it does not synthesize, it says that the right part of the / has to be a power of 2

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use this division_core like a function, which is probably not possible. if you want a vhdl function that implements division, that is different from using a component.